# In a pair of diastereomers, which of the following is true?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, chirality

While going through my book, I came across this question and got really confused. Here's what the problem was:

> In a pair of diastereomers,
>
> 1. Both can be laevo-rotatory or both can be dextro-rotatory
> 2. Both can be optically inactive
> 3. One can be optically active other can be optically inactive
> 4. Presence of two chiral carbons is must in both of the isomer

As you can see, this is a multiple correct problem.

---

I tried going with the definition, **Diastereomers are stereoisomers whose molecules are not mirror images of each other**

Also, to satisfy this, I believe there should at least be two chiral carbons. So option (4) seems right. But I'm really not able to figure out the others. How can we determine this?

Comment: You can have chirality around heteroatoms e.g. Esomeprazole

Comment: This might be easiest to think about if you picture a polyol, like glycerol or [xylitol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylitol), but even longer.  Every carbon except the ones on the end has a chiral center.  But can you make more than one stereoisomer with a mirror plane that is optically inactive?  Can they rotate light the same direction?  It should be easy to think about from there.

Comment: I think all the options are correct. The definition directly leads to all of them.

Comment: They’re all true except for 4. You don’t need chiral carbons for optical activity. Other heteroatoms will work. And even molecules with restricted rotation around a signal bond can show optical activity.